# .htaccess rewrite URL without its change

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to make `www.site.com/web/name` to be understood as `www.site.com/web?system=name` (without the change in URL)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ $1?system=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ $1?system=$2
```

.htacceess is located in /web.

This doesn't do anything! Where is my mistake?

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: @anubhava In /web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these rules in `web/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ ?system=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Also note that `\w` is shortcut of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and `QSA` flag is for preserving original query string.

Comment: No, it gives "Page doesn't work. Redirected you too many times."

Comment: Tried in incognito. It doesn't redirect to `?system=`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189102/discussion-between-anubhava-and-leeloo).